# Issue for updating device name in homegraph from sync message

Tags: google-smart-home

My fullfillment system is responced when sync intent is received.
If I change device name using our system, and then it will be responsed new device name to homgraph through sync message.
I responce new device name to use below name field("name": devices[j]['nickName'],) for changing new name in home app.
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync

I think it doesn't work.
When I restart Google Home app, my device still has the previous name.
Hou could I update my device name?

This is my sync message.

```
                 var device = JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        'id' : devices[j]['deviceId'],
                        "type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
                        "traits": [
                            "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
                            "action.devices.traits.Brightness"
                        ],
                        "name": {
                            "defaultNames": [
                                "light"
                            ],
                            "name": devices[j]['nickName'],
                            "nicknames": [
                                devices[j]['nickName']
                            ]
                        },
                        "roomHint": rooms[i]['roomAlias'],
                        "willReportState": true,
                        "attributes": {
                        },
                        "deviceInfo": {
                        },
                        "customData": {
                            "device_type": "BedLight"
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user change name of a device through the Google Home App (GHA), then this method of updating the name takes precedence over any other form of updating. The developer will not be able to override the change of name through a SYNC response.
The values passed for name in your SYNC response are only for providing an initial name to the device (before the user changes the name of the device). If you want the new name of the device to be reflected in GHA then you will need to unlink your account and re-link it again.